# UC3907DW which pins are the two batteries?

Tags: power, power-management

I have a project and want to power it from smart phone power banks.

Now 2.1 ampere at 5 volt is not enough to power a motor.

I want to combine multiple power banks (4) to provide enough current and voltage to the motor.

My issue is, most discussions warn against linking up the power banks directly.

UC3907DW is a microchip, which distributes the current it draws across multiple devices.

Now, I have seen the documentation fro this microchip; found here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3907.pdf?ts=1626506550271&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUC3907

It does not clearly explain which four pins are required for the two batteries and which two pins are the output.

Can someone help? Any other information is also appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Almost exclusively, motors in portable applications are powered by batteries directly. There's no benefit from the stable 5V voltage, and it is not a very high voltage, limiting your choice of motors. Is there any constraint that forces you to use powerbanks? Why not batteries + BMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It does not clearly explain which four pins are required for the two batteries and which two pins are the output.

Because it isn't used like that, you need one per power source.

See the diagram on page 6.

You need to create a shared current sense bus as well as power buses.